# Android App Exits on Press on Back Button Instead of Navigating to Previous Screen - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, button, dart, back

This is main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'List',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        ),
        home: HomeScreen());
  }
}
```

This is homescreen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  int _currentindex = 0;
  final List<Widget> screen = [
    DashboardNavigator(),
    RegisterPage(),
  ];

  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text('Are you sure ?'),
      content: new Text('Do you want to exit ?'),
      actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right:10.0,bottom:10.0),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          child: Text("No",
          style:TextStyle(
            color:Colors.red
          )),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 16),
        new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
          child: Text("Yes",
          style:TextStyle(
            color:Colors.green
          )),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ) ??
      false;
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop:_onBackPressed,
    child:Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: IndexedStack(
              index:_currentindex,
              children: screen,
            )
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: _currentindex,
            onTap: (int index) {
              this.setState(() {
                _currentindex = index;
                }
              );
            },
            items:[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home,color:Colors.green),title:Text('Home')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings_ethernet,color:Colors.green),title:Text('Console')),
            ]
          )
    ));
  }
}
```

This is the Navigator Widget

```
class DashboardNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  DashboardNavigator({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardNavigatorState createState() => _DashboardNavigatorState();
}

class _DashboardNavigatorState extends State<DashboardNavigator> {

  String url;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            switch(settings.name) {
              case '/':
                return DashBoard();
              case '/listhub':
                return ListHub();
              case '/listhub/listfarmer':
                return ListFarmer(url);
            }
          },
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I used Navigator.pushNamed function to navigate between these screen

`onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context,"/listhub"),`

but when i click on the android back button it closes the app instead of 
navigating to the previous page ... I tried WillpopScope in each page but it doesn't work.

Please Suggest me the correct way to navigate back to the previous screen using android back button and also appBar back button.

Comment: maybe the DashboardNavigator was already popped when you get back? can you post the whole code? including the origin

Comment: I have posted my whole code, please check it whether you can help it out ?

Comment: I am having the same thing back button pressed simply exits the app. if we click on back button on appbar or do programatically Navigator.pop it goes to the prev screen. 
@RubanThilak will you able to solve the problme

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because you're pushing to your own `Navigator` while the OS level back gesture and your `_onBackPressed` function are popping from MaterialApp's navigator. Since the latter hasn't had any routes pushed it, it behaves as expected and exits the app.

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66349) Github issue covers the problem in detail with a couple different solutions. You could create a global key in main and pass it to materialApp using the `navigatorKey` argument and to `DashboardNavigator` using its key argument. This way, both MaterialApp and your DashboardNavigator will use the same navigator wherever you push or pop.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I make it works by referring [this](https://gist.github.com/orestesgaolin/67e10b51e725c0d8abe8f386263feea1):

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();//define a navigation key.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My APP',
        navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,//this is the navigation key
        onGenerateRoute: (_) => null,
        builder: (context, child) {
            return Navigator(
                key: _navigatorKey,//same navigation key
                pages: [
                    MaterialPage(
                      key: const ValueKey('homepage'),
                      child: HomPage(),//homepage widget
                     ....
                ],
                onPopPage: (route, result) {
                   //pop logic here. 
                }
            );
        }
     );
  }
}
```

The discussion [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66349) also mention using `WillPopScope` wrapper, maybe you can try this as well.